# Can the sum of the first n squares of primes be a perfect square?

Tags: prime-numbers, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

So far, all I have found is for $n=1$, for which the square is 4. (Rather trivial)

To give some context, I recently watched the Numberphile video 
[Squared Squares](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoRjwZomUK0).

Basically, a squared square is a square that is entirely made up of other integral squares (preferably all of different sizes). I wanted to see whether there exists a squared square made of $n$ squares that is entirely composed of squares with the side-lengths of all primes up to the $n$th prime.

By finding an example that satisfies the question, it will be shown that there is at least the *possibility* for one of these squares existing. If it can be proven that there are no examples other than $n=1$, then it follows that no squared square with conditions exist.

Answer (score 6):

There are no others up to $n= 10^6$.  I strongly suspect there are none.
The sum of the first $n$ squares of primes is on the order of $n^3 \log^2(n)$, and heuristically the probability that it is a square is on the order of $n^{-3/2} \log(n)^{-1}$.  The series $\sum_n n^{-3/2}/\log(n)$ converges, so
we should expect to find only finitely many squares.  This is not a proof, but together with the empirical evidence it is highly suggestive.

EDIT:  Here is a Maple program which uses all the primes $< 3 \times 10^7$ (there are $1857859$ of them).  Still no more found.

```
P:=select(isprime, [2,seq(i,i=3..3*10^7,2)]):
S:= ListTools:-PartialSums(map(t -> t^2, P)):
select(t -> issqr(S[t]), [$1..nops(S)]);
```

$$ [1] $$

---

**P.S.** By the way, if you use the primes $p_n$ themselves rather than squares of primes, then solutions to,

$$\sum_{n=1}^k p_n = s^2$$

are OEIS sequences [A033997](https://oeis.org/A033997) (for $k$) and [A061888](https://oeis.org/A061888) (for $s$) the largest known so far is,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{126789311423} p_n = 468726713734^2$$

but which is likely to be infinite.

Comment: As shown by Patrick's answer, there is at least one solution above $n = 10^6$

Comment: @infinitylord, where is Patrick's answer?  Could you link to it?

Comment: The source was a search in Maple.

Comment: Patrick's answer was deleted.  Apparently his programming was in error.

Comment: @Wildcard: Yes, in his deleted answer (which some of us can still see) he claims $$2+3+5+\dots+11765499 \overset{?}= 4183065^2$$ But $11765499$ is **not** even prime and the sum is wrong since,  $$2+3+5+\dots+11765499 \approx 2095226.12^2$$ And the OP was looking for _squares_ of primes.